# Error message when try to install program say (cx_freeze:python error in main script)

Tags: python

I get this error message when it try to install program, it appear there some packages need to be installed

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0Ppq.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate on how you tried to install it at first?

Either way, I recommend you use the following process to download Python modules in the future.

1. https://pypi.org/project/cx_Freeze/
   Download the .whl file for cx-freeze above
2. Make sure you have wheel installed and execute the following command:

python -m pip install cx-freeze

Comment: I get this error when i try to install another program not python